# why padding left is not working on the bootstrap program version 5.3.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-tags-input

```
</head>
<body>
    <header class="bg-info "> 
        <div class="container">
      
        <div class="row text-white">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-3 pl-6 ">     
          
                <h2>Jebin Tom</h2>                  
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-6  ">         

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

`your text`
here pl is not working
why pl is not working on it i am using bootstrap version 5.3.1

Comment: "left" and "right" were replaced by "start" and "end" in Bootstrap 5. So, `ps-6` instead of `pl-6`. Although I don't exactly remember any values higher than `ps-5`. Probably want to read the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure in bootstrap 5, padding left is made with `ps` where s stands for start.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 4**, the **pl** class moves to the left while in **Bootstrap 5**, the **ps** class moves to the left.